# Getting error when try to upgrade packages distro-info-data : Breaks: distro-info

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, upgrade, dependencies

I've a **Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS** on my server I've updated my packages by running `sudo apt update` but when I run `sudo apt upgrade` I get error of **unmet dependencies**
this is my os info

```
$ lsb_release -a
```

**Output**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS 
Release:    20.04 
Codename:   focal
```

---

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

**Error**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 distro-info-data : Breaks: distro-info (< 0.20~) but 0.18ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
 dpkg : Breaks: libapt-pkg5.0 (< 1.7~b) but 1.6.14 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Because of this I'm not able to install some of my packages.

**Note** : I've tried this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337376/apt-upgrade-error-distro-info-data-breaks-distro-info)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apt upgrade error: distro-info-data breaks distro-info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337376/apt-upgrade-error-distro-info-data-breaks-distro-info)

Comment: Hello @SiGe no it's not

Comment: Hello @SiGe my `sources.list.d` folder don't have any files in it it's empty

Comment: `grep -r /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` please [edit] your question for output.

Comment: Hello @nobody `sources.list.d` does not contain any files & I figured out answer I've replaced my `sources.list` from diffrent server `sources.list` and it worked for me should I provide updated `sources.list` in question ?

Comment: No if your error is gone then no need.

Comment: Hello @nobody should I add that `sources.list` as an answer or close this question